# Mongo DB Multiple Primary Keys

Tags: mongodb, primary-key, sharding

I want to have a multiple fields in mongodb as primary keys so that there won't be any duplicates with compound key. 
In normal mongodb this can be achieved using ensureIndex() function.
I want to know how this can be done in shard environment and i can't keep the compound key as shard key.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make the compound value a new column, and make it the primary key(if that unique is enough) or 
shard key. Mutiple unique indexes could be a problem  in shard environment,  according to MongodbDB,

> For sharded collections
>   these unique indexes cannot enforce uniqueness because insert and
>   indexing operations are local to each shard.
>
> MongoDB does not support unique indexes across shards, except when the
>   unique index contains the full shard key as a prefix of the index. In
>   these situations MongoDB will enforce uniqueness across the full key,
>   not a single field.

Comment: thanks for quick response. I already mentioned that i can't use index in shard environment and i can't use the compound key as the shard key. Can you please elaborate what do you mean by compound value to a new column